# How to accept null values in ASP.NET template field?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written as below lines of code

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="LicenceTypesNames" HeaderText="Licence Required">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lnkNameLT" runat="server" Text='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("LicenceTypesNames").Replace(",",", ")) %>'>    </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("LicenceTypesNames").Replace(",",", "))` is not working. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%# (Eval("LicenceTypesNames")!=null)?Eval("LicenceTypesNames").ToString().Replace(",",", ") : "" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a databinding statement like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lnkNameLT" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("LicenceTypesNames") == null ? "" : "with value" %>'>
</asp:Label>
```